# How complex can I make a classifier's loss function in Scikit-Learn?

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model, loss-function

I want to customize the loss vanilla loss function being used by scikit-learn classifiers like the Logistic Regression classifier, etc.

For example, if the vanilla empirical risk minimization formulation is as follows,

[image]

how can I change it to something like this?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: `LogisticRegression` does support the L1 and L2 penalties, but otherwise I agree with @StefanPopov's answer that it's not generally possible.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/discussions/21614) I am afraid that's not possible.

In my experience working with the library, I have never worked on a use case that required such modification, I mostly change the values for the arguments in the constructor of the estimators.

I think that if you want to customise an algorithm (e.g., logistic regression) more, then you'd have to implement it yourself. On the other hand, I've found this StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54267745/implementing-custom-loss-function-in-scikit-learn) that specifies how you can implement a custom loss function for `sklearn` estimators, so maybe there's a workaround for it, even though it seems that the library was not designed to be used like that.

Comment: That SO question is about custom metrics (used for hyperparameter tuning e.g.), not the actual loss function being optimized by the model.